# Как отобразить содержимое папки через localhost?

Tags: php

Запустил для выбранной папки (назовем ее base) встроенный сервер PHP через командную строку (php -S localhost:80).
Внутри этой папки лежит файл index.php, а также другие папки.
Требуется в браузере отобразить содержимое папки (назовем ее demo), входящей в исходную (base).
Если в адресной строке браузера ввести localhost, отображается содержимое файла index.php.
Если же ввести localhost/demo, браузер выдает "The requested resource /demo was not found on this server."

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Comment: проще настроить alias в apache или nginx, чем заниматься ерундой. Всё это делается без привлечения php